# Behat is skipping the tests

Tags: testing, bdd, behat, cakephp-3.x

I'm new to behat.

My local development environment is as below:

- Docker env.
- I've installed behat through composer
- I have sample code as below in the .feature file

### Behat test

```
 Scenario: Get bounced back emails                                                 
    When I request "tender_manager_contact_relationships/getBouncedBackEmails/1024" 
    Then I should receive a successful response
```

### Command

```
 vendor/bin/behat /var/www/xyz/features/get_bounced_back_emails.feature
```

### Output

```
--- Skipped scenarios:

    features/get_bounced_back_emails.feature:6

1 scenario (1 skipped)
3 steps (2 skipped)
0m0.38s (12.33Mb)
```

Why my test is being skipped? Can anyone guide me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

- It seems my behat base url was not able to connect to my api on localhost :83 so it was skipping all the tests.
- I am using Guzzle and it is using windows IP 192.x.x.12:83.
- Now I have replaced behat base url with my windows IP 192.x.x.12:83 and it started working.